# Replace element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When developing apps for android through phonegap using html there is a noticeable flicker when switching pages. This is caused from loading in a new html file.

Can this be avoided by replacing an element on click and having it fade in?

I don't mind using Javascript or Jquery but I can't seem to find a way using just html and css.

I'm basically creating a childrens interactive story/book. So clicking the goback or goforth buttons will load in new content, without effecting the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to understand what is causing your flicker, but since you've given us no information to go on, there's not much we can say about that.

It's pretty easy to replace an element with plain javascript:

```
function replaceElem(origElem, newElem) {
    var parent = origElem.parentNode;
    parent.insertBefore(newElem, origElem);
    parent.removeChild(origElem);
}
```

If you want to fade the new element in, you can do that with a CSS transition or a library that supports animations.

If you want the new element to fadeIn over the top of the old element, then you have to play some games with overlapping objects and positioning and only remove the old element after the new element is fully faded in.  That is very doable, but not as simple as just replacing one element with the other.

---

One simpler way is to just have both sets of HTML in the original page:

```
<div id="page1" class="page">
    <div>Other HTML here</div>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="page" style="display: none;">
    <div>Other HTML here</div>
</div>
```

And, then you can hide show only a particular page like this:

```
function showPage(id) {
    // hide all pages
    var pages = document.querySelectAll(".page");
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        pages.style.display = "none";
    }
    // show one particular page
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

// show page 2
showPage("page2");
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. 
Would this work as an entire page as well ? 
So for example, I have a "goback" and "goforth" button and each respective click would bring in a new page with all their containing elements?

Comment: @user3464627 - it will work with any two objects and all their decendant objects.  So, if you have two container objects that hold lots of other DOM elements, you can swap them too using this function.  Just pass in the two container elements and it will swap them.  This function assumes the HTML is already loaded into DOM elements and you've got handles to the DOM elements.

Comment: but in order to replace an element I'll have to first define it in my html file along with the css. 
How can I effectively 'hide' the other elements? for example.
<div id="page1"></div> Shows on load
<div id="page2"></div> Shows on click
<div id="page3"></div> Shows on click

Comment: You can just mark one element with CSS `display: none`; and the other as `display: block` via either class name and stylesheet or direct style attribute in the HTML.  Then, if you just reverse the two display states with javascript, you don't even have to replace them.  This is a common way to implement tabbed or paged content if the content is not too large.

Comment: ahh I see, I think I may have been asking the wrong question initially then. Have you got a code example of that by any chance ?

Comment: @user3464627 - see what I added to my answer.